# Apache redirect page to bad vhost

Tags: apache, redirect, dns

In bind I use CNAME as redirector from old.domain.com to new.domain.com
also old.domain was vhost which I deleted
Each vhost have http redirection to https, but the problem is that when typing old address in webbrowser I get redirect to diff.domain.com even when dig/nslookup see dns cname.
When I disable that one vhost the next diff2.domain.com get redirected

```
<VirtualHost ip:80>
        ServerName diff.domain.com
        Redirect permanent / https://diff.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<IFModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost ip:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
                ServerName diff.domain.com:443
                DocumentRoot /var/www/diff/web
                <Directory "/var/www/diff/web">
                        Options FollowSymLinks
                        AllowOverride All
                        Order allow,deny
                        Allow from all
                        Require all granted
                </Directory>
                ErrorLog /var/www/diff/logs/error.log
                CustomLog /var/www/diff/logs/access.log combined
                SSLEngine on
                SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/diff/fullchain.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/diff/privkey.pem
                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

                BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                                nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                                downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
                # MSIE 7 and newer should be able to use keepalive
                BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

                <IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
                        AddType application/x-httpd-fastphp5 .php
                        Action application/x-httpd-fastphp5 /php5-fcgi
 Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi_diff
                        FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi_diff -socket /var/run/php5-fpm_diff.sock -pass-header Authorization
                 </IfModule>
        </VirtualHost>
</IFModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I use this conf as tample to others vhost but it looks like there is a bug/error somewhere here

Answer (score 1):

Apache 2.4 read site configs in order.
It look like there wasn't any hit with url in any ServerName or ServerAlias, so apache load first readed site config which was diff.domain.

I end up adding  with ServerName that represented the url I wanted and Redirected it to site I wanted.

That way im sure where the page goes.

CNAME pointed on IP it was no different than A record in this case.

Now i know more. Hope this will help someone in future ;-)